# Can not see the 840 nodes I am supposed to have created with Neo4j by importing them from a csv file

Tags: node.js, database, csv, neo4j, cypher

I am new on Neo4J. I am using Cypher to create nodes from the import of a csv file containing on each row the user ID, name and email.

I use this line of code:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT                                                                                                
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Users/Cam/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb/import/node_attributes.csv" AS data               
create (u:User {id:data.Id, name:data.displayName, email:data.email})
```

it seems to work as I have this message: 
Added 840 labels, created 840 nodes, statement completed in 334 ms.

but when I go on neo4j in the database section; I see that only 25 nodes have been created and that they use only 2 names of my users....

any idea to know how to see them ?
thanks in advance

Comment: What query are you using to see your nodes? Also, can you provide a screenshot of what you're seeing in the database section?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the neo4j browser? When you click on a label (or `*`) in the `Node labels` section on the left side, it automatically includes a `LIMIT 25` clause to the generated Cypher code (to avoid swamping the the UI if there is a lot of data, and to avoid possibly taking too long to respond). For example:

```
MATCH (n) RETURN n LIMIT 25
```

If this is your situation, just remove the `LIMIT 25` clause to see all your data. For example:

```
MATCH (n) RETURN n
```

Comment: many thanks. I will do that. indeed, this limit of 25 is written. wish you a good day:-)